# CXF @CrossOriginResourceSharing Annotation

Tags: rest, cors, cxf, karaf

I am using CXF/Karaf, and I have many different RESTful resources within multiple packages/classes.

**Question**: Is there a way to avoid having to write annotations above every resource, such as `@CrossOriginResourceSharing`?

I would like to be able to put this in one place. Below is an example of how this is currently being used:

```
@CrossOriginResourceSharing(
    allowOrigins = {"http://<ip>:<port>"}
)
@GET
@Path("/rest")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String rest();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to the class instead of on each resource in the class (and I haven't tested this but you could possible create a super class with this annotation and extend it but I'm not sure if CXF will honour it):

```
@CrossOriginResourceSharing(
    allowOrigins = {"http://<ip>:<port>"}
)
public class resourceGroup {

    @GET
    @Path("/rest")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String rest();

}
```